# {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error' in sso Api call forms authentication

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5

Here i am using the forms authentication in web.config:

```
   <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" path="/" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".xyz.com" />

</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

the problem is that :(Here i am call the api url..but it will not call the proper way..and instead of it will redirect to other url just like below)

```
var response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
```

Here is the apiUrl:

```
http://localhost:1849/Api/Ticket?UserId=10&start=0&length=10&searchstr=&orders=0&orderDir=asc
```

but it instead of call this api it will call the

```
http://localhost:1849/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fApi%2fTicket%3fUserId%3d10%26start%3d0%26length%3d10%26searchstr%3d%26orders%3d0%26orderDir%3dasc&UserId=10&start=0&length=10&searchstr=&orders=0&orderDir=asc
```

so how do i call the above api???

Answer (score 0):

You've got a deny for anonymous users on your whole site by the looks of it. You'll need to be authenticated first.

You can use the location tag in your web.config to allow anonymous access to your login page so that you can authenticate them and then it will allow access to your api.

Since you're using an API, you might need to use a different authentication method than a login page.

Comment: Ok but How do i authenticate??

Comment: How do you want to choose whether someone can access your api?

Comment: sir here i am login from different project..and store the credentials using form authentication Iprincple and use the same things to login here...you want to do the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SubAdmin")]..and if i delete the above form authentication in web.config then it will working fine

Comment: is there any method to stop..to redirect??

Comment: Could you change your authentication cookie to work off a wildcard domain (assuming your api on on a sub-domain)? The reason you are redirecting is because they are not authenticated and your config it telling it to return to the login page.